# jQuery Slideshow from XML with date parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

So I have been tasked with creating a jQuery slideshow from an XML file with a timing mechanism to change the images based on date. I have the slideshow working from the XML, but I am struggling with adding the date feature. I would like to be able to "turn on" and "turn off" images based on the onDate and offDate. I understand Javascript is not the best way to show things based on date, but there are limits within the current site structure that prevent server side timing. So I would like to have the ability to load up say 10 images, and then only show three based on what today's date is, and what the onDate/offDate are.

This is the logic I was thinking.... If today is < onDate .hide or if today is > offDate .hide else .show

Where I am struggling

1. The correct way to enter the date in the XML file.
2. Parsing the date from XML into something that Javascript and in turn jQuery can use to compare today's date with the date in XML and  show the image accordingly.
3. Once the date has been established figuring out a way to show or hide the specific image based on date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

XML

```
<eq-banner>
    <id>1</id>
    <url>linktopage.html</url>
    <img>image.jpg</img>
    <dept>equipment</dept>
    <onDate>12/01/2010</onDate>
    <offDate>12/31/2010</offDate>
    <copy>FREE Stuff</copy>
</eq-banner>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "rotationData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
});
});

function xmlParser(equipment) {

$(equipment).find('eq-banner').each(function() {                    

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var dept = $(this).find('dept').text();
        var url = $(this).find('url').text();
        var img = $(this).find('img').text();

        $('<div class="'+dept+'"</div>').html('<a href="'+url+'"><img src="images/'+img+'" /></a><br />').appendTo('#apparel')
            $("#equipment").cycle({
                fx:"fade", 
                speed:100,
                timeout:5000
                    });;

            });

}

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="equipment">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the data quality of the XML source, specifically that the dates are all well-formed as in your sample, it's pretty easy to turn that into a JavaScript "Date" object:

```
var str = "12/31/2010";

var pieces = str.split('/');
var date = new Date(~~str[2], ~~str[0] - 1, ~~str[1]);
```

(The `~~` trick converts the strings to numbers; do that however you prefer.) Also months are numbered from zero, and hence the subtraction.

Comparing dates works perfectly well in JavaScript, or you can call the ".getTime()" method on a date to explicitly get a "milliseconds since the epoch" value to compare instead.

As to how you'd show/hide the images, I'd be inclined to conditionally add a class to elements to be hidden (or shown; whichever makes the most sense).

Comment: Some locales list month before day in the '##/##/####' format, others list day before month. Parsing this format is not reliable. Instead, months should be spelled out.

Comment: That's why I qualified the answer with the first paragraph. If the OP has control of the source data, date representation variations are not an issue (unless the OP is nuts or something :-)

Comment: OP certainly can be nuts. But I will be the one entering the dates, so it can and will be consistent.

Comment: Ha ha well then that should work out just fine :-)  @mblase75 is correct of course, that dates are represented in zillions of possible ways "in the wild".

Answer (score 0):

XML doesn't have a "correct" way of handling dates, and JavaScript can parse just about anything. However, the most JS-friendly format would be something like "October 20, 2011" with the time optionally added in "12:34:56" format. A string like that can be fed directly to the new Date() constructor and be parsed correctly regardless of location.

```
datestr = "October 20, 2011";
date = new Date(datestr);
```

To compare Date objects, just use < or > -- however, a JS Date object contains a time element which will also be compared. So if you create a new Date object for the present with `var now = new Date();` and compare it to `var dat = new Date("string with today's date");` you'll find that `dat` is less than `now` because `dat` has time `00:00:00` while `now` has the present time. If this is a problem, you'll have to explicitly compare `Date.getDate()`, `Date.getMonth()` and `Date.getFullYear()` all at once. ( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp )

Comment: The images will usually go up and come down at midnight. So the hours, minutes, seconds doesn't really matter. The main thing is the date. Plus the time zone doesn't really matter either. I am just focused on sharing content in the US, and since I am on the east coast, it will always go up first. I will be responsible for entering the dates, so I have control over the integrity of the data.